# Is there a way to log each and every executing query and its corresponding result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement, where I want to log each and every executing query and it's corresponding results set to a log file in mysql. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Ex:-

Query: select * country_name from countries_tbl

Result: USA, China, Japan

Comment: The "query" and the "result", seriously? You need the result of each query to be saved to a log? What are you trying to achieve exactly? Is this for auditing of access or what?

Answer (score 1):

For having all queries in a log file you need to activate general log file by adding this into the configuration file of mysql below section [mysqld] :

`general_log
general_log_file=/path/to/the/general_log_file`

Next if you want to have output of specific queries in a file you need to add the following instruction at the end of query : 
`into outfile /tmp/output_query`

for example : 
`select version() into outfile /tmp/output_query`

If you want to have output in a file from an entire MySQL client session write this in mysql client :

`tee /tmp/output`

That command tells MySQL to log both the input and output of your current MySQL login session to a file named /tmp/my.out.

As far as now there is no other way to have queries + output in a same log file, but maybe someone with much knowledge can confirm this.